# Can't read file from external storage on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, genymotion, android-file

I'm trying to load a file from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` into a `SoundPool`. The file exists, but still I get

```
E/SoundPool: error loading /storage/emulated/0/dialpad/sounds/mamacita_us/one.mp3
```

when I try to load it. On a real device it works perfectly, from the exact same path.

This is the code I'm using to load the file:

```
if( isExternalStorageReadable() ){
    String externalStorageAbsolutePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String soundFilesPath = (new File(externalStorageAbsolutePath, "dialpad/sounds/mamacita_us")).getPath();

    Log.d("DEBUG", (new File(soundFilesPath, "one.mp3")).getAbsolutePath() );
    Log.d("DEBUG", (new File(soundFilesPath, "one.mp3")).exists() ? "EXISTS" : "DOES NOT EXSIST");

    sounds.put("1", soundPool.load((new File(soundFilesPath, "one.mp3")).getAbsolutePath(), 1));
    sounds.put("2", soundPool.load( (new File(soundFilesPath, "two.mp3")).getPath(), 1 ));
}
```

`isExternalStorageReadable()` is a helper method:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The LogCat outputs say

```
D/DEBUG: /storage/emulated/0/dialpad/sounds/mamacita_us/one.mp3
D/DEBUG: EXISTS
```

I had an idea that perhaps it was a file permission issue, but I don't know... `ls -l` in `adb shell` gives me

```
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_rw    18288 2009-07-06 13:42 one.mp3
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_rw    21422 2009-07-06 13:44 two.mp3
```

Have tried changing the permissions using `chmod` but they never change. I've used `adb push` to push the files to the emulator.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this? As I said it's working perfectly on a real device for the same path, so it seems to be an issue with the Genymotion emulator and/or file system. The emulator is running Android 6.0 (API23).

Oh, and yes I'm declaring

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is considered a"dangerous permission" under the new runtime permissions model introduced in Android 6.0.

You will need to request permission to access the external storage.

Your device is probably running an Android version <6.0 so it will work on that without requesting permission.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous